# Ripping BluRay Audio Streams

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a bluray audio disc.  I've been trying to identify the streams with ffplay but I'm not sure how to do so.  I was following the guide on gentoo's website, however ffplay does't show me the available streams.  I've tried several versions of ffmpeg to rip the files however I get the mesage Invalid data found when processing input.  I mounted the bluray drive and within the mounted drive is the folder BDMV/STREAM.  In this folder are four files: 00000.m2ts, 00001.m2ts, 00002.m2ts, and 00003.m2ts.  I assume they are all audio streams since it is an audi bluray disc.  However no matter what ffmpeg commands I enter I keep seeming to get the same error message. "Invalid data found when processing input."

Any ideas?  I would prefer to do this on linux, as the windows software is proprietary.  Also I do not want to use makemkv if possible as I want to rip the bluray audio as lossless, such as wav or preferably flac (which I supposed I can convert to wav).  Either way I'm sure I'm using ffmpeg wrong as well as ffplay.  Can someone please assist me in the proper approach to rip blueray audio streams from a bluray audio disc? Thanks

Comment: Does the disc contain any copy protection on it? (Pretty much every movie you buy will).

Comment: Yes it turns out it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your question: https://cloudconvert.org/m2ts-to-mp3

Comment: 1 GB size limit for the free option. Also, uploading large files to a webservice might prove difficult because of connection issues.